# query to find unique pairs of numbers

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

create table pairs( number a,number b)

where the data is

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

etc.

what query gives me the unique pairs? 
With this i mean:

```
1,2 or 2,1
1,3    3,1
2,3    3,2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the simplest solution. If it can be guaranteed that there are no duplicated pairs then the `GROUP BY` isn't needed.

```
SELECT a, b 
FROM pairs
WHERE a < b
GROUP BY a, b
```

Output:

```
a   b   
1   2
1   3
2   3
```

You can always change the `<` to `>` if you want the alternate output:

```
a   b   
2   1
3   1
3   2
```

As @TimBiegeleisen pointed out, it could even be further simplified to

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b 
FROM pairs
WHERE a < b
```

I'm not sure which of these queries might be the fastest.

Comment: Hi stef, glad to help. If it did answer your question please mark it accepted so that other users will be able to find it more easily. Thanks.

Comment: done.I cant upvote for now cause i am new around here.Thanks a lot again.

Comment: No problem on the upvote, what makes the site better is just getting the answer accepted.

Comment: Or just `SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM pairs WHERE a < b`

Comment: @Nick `DISTINCT` is often implemented under the hood in MySQL using `GROUP BY`, so I would actually expect both to have the same execution plan.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just did a quick explain... looks like `DISTINCT` is probably faster as both use where and a temporary table but `GROUP BY` also does a filesort because of the implicit ordering. Need to add an `ORDER BY NULL` to make it not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a least/greatest trick here:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(a, b), GREATEST(a, b)
FROM yourTable
WHERE a <> b
GROUP BY
    LEAST(a, b), GREATEST(a, b);
```

To see why this works, consider the two pairs `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)`.  In both cases, the least resolves to `1` and the greatest to `2`, so both pairs would be reported as the same thing according to the logic in my query.

We could also tighten this up to the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(a, b), GREATEST(a, b)
FROM yourTable
WHERE a <> b;
```

Note: If you want to return pairs where `a = b`, then remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Wow! Smart solution.

Comment: Surely this returns 3,3 ?!?!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03bf49/2)

Comment: @Strawberry Adding an ```WHERE a<>b```  condition would help.

Comment: i found the right solution with this in mysql workbench.Indeed that was very smart nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sub.output FROM
(
SELECT  CONCAT(a,b, ' or ',
b,a ) output,
ASCII(a)+ASCII(b) asci
FROM tbl_t1 WHERE a!=b
) sub GROUP BY sub.asci;
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.